# Why does ~(ushort)1 returns an int?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Why does `~(ushort)1` return an `int` of value `-2`? I assume the -2 value would be because of the flipped bits but what's the reason behind it being implicitly cast back to an int?

PS: I was not implicitly converting it to an int. If you write to the console `(~(ushort)1).GetType().ToString()` you will get `System.Int32` printed out.

Comment: @Servy you're right, I missed the last answer, which explains _why_ that happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21174841/5012558.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ushort` lacks bitwise operators, unlike `int`, `uint`, `long` and `ulong` - as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-complement-operator).

As such, the `ushort` is promoted to an `int` before applying the bitwise negation.